# setContentOffset is not scrolling table to last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to scroll the table to last row using contentOffset method.This method works fine when data is not much but if user has scrolled to much it does take table to last cell. I am using the following code

```
   self.delegate.table.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, table.contentSize.height -  table.frame.size.height), animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the preferred way would be calling

```
func scrollToRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
          at scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition, 
    animated: Bool)
```

at the `UITableView`, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow)

Comment: When I use this method it takes so much time if number of cells are large.

Comment: What if you set animated to false?

Comment: result is same in both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `scrollToRow` method.

```
let lastIndex:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1, inSection: 0)

tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
```

The time this takes to scroll is based on the contentSize. Strangely this time is still used when animated is set to false. To make it more snappy set your own duration in an animation block.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(aSmallValue) { 
            self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: Because if number of cells are large,it takes too much time to scroll.

Comment: please see my revised answer about the slowness

Comment: since when did xcode started compiling obj-C code in swift file?

Comment: Still it is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me,
code for objective-c

```
 NSIndexPath *scrollIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1) inSection:0];
 [[self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:scrollIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
```

Code for Swift 3.0

```
 let scrollIndexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: (tblView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1), section: 0)
 tblView.scrollToRow(at: scrollIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let offsetOfTable = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.yourTableView.contentSize.height - self.yourTableView.frame.size.height + self.FOOTER_HEIGHT);
self.yourTableView.contentOffset = offsetOfTable;
```